# How to show a drillthrough report below a main report in SSRS 2008 R2 using the reportviewer

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, reporting-services

I'm using the ReportViewer with ServerReports, SSRS 2008 R2 and VB.NET.  I'm using the "Go to Report" Action to link the reports together. The default functionality when clicking a link on an SSRS report is to replace that report with the drillthrough report.  Instead I would like to keep the main report there, and display the drillthrough report as a seperate ReportViewer below it.

I somewhat found a way to achieve this, but it doesn't seem very efficient.  Below is the code I have so far (found from this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/9131fa89-458a-44d1-87ba-61f6a6f3d9e0)):

```
Public Sub SummaryDrillthroughHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DrillthroughEventArgs)

    e.Cancel = True 'Stop action from replacing main report as expected

    Dim rpic As ReportParameterInfoCollection = e.Report.GetParameters()
    Dim params As New List(Of ReportParameter)

    For Each param As ReportParameterInfo In rpic
        params.Add(New ReportParameter(param.Name, param.Values(0)))
    Next

    ReportViewer3.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("myReportServer")
    ReportViewer3.ServerReport.ReportPath = e.ReportPath
    ReportViewer3.ServerReport.SetParameters(params)

End Sub
```

This does work but it looks as if it is trying to load the report twice.  I wasn't able to find much documentation about the DrillthroughEventHandler, but the event seems to fire when the drillthrough report has already been fetched from the server and ready to render with all of the data.

So calling the code I have above would essentially load the report twice sequentially (once when the link is clicked in the main report and again when the drillthrough report parameters are set).  Looking in firebug I see each post event each taking about 8 seconds (the drillthrough report is a bit slow).  When I take out the code above and the drillthrough report replaces the main report, only 1 post is sent.

Is there a way to intercept the first call made to the drillthrough report and call it directly from the ReportViewer3 control with the needed parameters?  Am I missing something, this looks like a fairly common requirement?